# What would be local "docker test" command?

Tags: docker, testing, dockerhub

Docker official documentation standardizes a way to test images with the `sut` service in a `docker-compose.test.yml` file:
https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/builds/automated-testing/

Yet, the documentation does not provide any way to run those tests on another environment than the centralized Docker Hub.

At the same time, [another official documentation entry](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/builds/advanced/#override-build-test-or-push-commands) explains that it is possible to override the `test` command with hooks. Yet, there is no documentation for this elusive `test` command, nor any example on how to properly override it.

- Is there such thing as an actual test command?
- If not, how would a developer locally run the docker test following the proposed format on his local environment / on a custom docker registry system?
- What would be (*edit*)~an example~ **the default** `test` hook?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no actual test command in docker, only a convention for running tests in Hub. You can make your own convention for testing things locally. As best I can tell from the documentation, Hub is running something similar to the following:

```
docker-compose run sut
```

That may be extended with a timeout and cleanup process:

```
timeout 10m docker-compose run --rm sut
```

The example test hook override would be any command you needed to run instead of the one above to test your image. As for what should you include in a custom test script, that depends on what custom commands your custom images needs in it's custom test, in other words, it's custom to each use case.